# Fastest way to Orgrimmar from Thrallmar in Blasted Lands

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Assuming hearthstone is not available and there isn't a mage in the area, what's the fastest flight path + zeppelin + boat to get from Thrallmar in Blasted Lands back to Orgrimmar?

Comment: For reference, Thrallmar is in Hellfire Peninsula, in Outland.  The portal to Outland is in Blasted Lands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the Dark Portal to the Outland and take the portal back to Orgrimmar. It should be on your left once you arrive at the Stairway of Destiny (with your back facing the Dark Portal).

Comment: This answer was exact some time ago, nowadays the portal is on the left side of the Dark Portal right in outlands. So you don't have to actually cross the Dark Portal, and I think you actually can't do it even if you want xD